# Word for unprogressive or stuck in tradition. Starts with a D

Tags: single-word-requests

This has been bothering me for several days, I am so close to remembering it. There is a word that starts with a D that is often used by the younger left-leaning people to describe the older right-leaning people. It typically means stuck in tradition or unprogressive. It can mean backward also. Can anyone help me figure out what the word is? Example sentence: " My grandad and his "-" view of things is frustrating to deal with every thanksgiving."

Comment: Is it dinosaur?  Because  dinosaurs have been extinct for a very long time they are an example of something, or someone, who is not very  modern.   .

Comment: The word that comes to mind is "reactionary", which has the minor problem of not starting with 'D'.

Comment: @user888379 a traditionalist isn't reactionary .. .they might have viewpoints that seem against all that modern people believe it.. but they had them before those modern beliefs developed.  Now, traditionalists might call for reactionary laws to role back new ones that have been put in place...so there might be some overlap for sure...especially among those so certain new ideas of tolerance have an indisputable moral high-ground.

Comment: antediluvian? (I know it doesn't start with a D, but I'm almost never correct when I think I know what letter a forgotten word starts with.)

Comment: I understand that. In the process I am learning all manner of words I didnt know before. Still that isn't it.

Comment: @Tom22 I wasn't simply equating 'traditionalist' with 'reactionary'. Given the nature of the question, I was figuring that the OP was looking for a word that had pejorative connotations, and might be applied somewhat indiscrimately.

Comment: @user888379  fair enough on hoping to satisfy the OP's intent.

Comment: Perhaps troglodyte?

Answer (score 2):

**dogmatic**
*adjective*

> inclined to lay down principles as incontrovertibly true.

Comment: This is what I think of too although it doesn't only apply to unprogressive people/opinions, it is often a feature. Ref - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dogmatic

Comment: Again, that does work here but it isnt the one I was looking for.

Comment: @S.Guyton Could it be draconian?

Answer (score 1):

See if it was **doctrinaire**.

> [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doctrinaire): stubbornly or excessively devoted to a doctrine or theory without regard to practical considerations.

Other fitting terms are **unreconstructed** and **dyed-in-the-wool**.

Comment: That does work there but that isn't the word I was thinking of.

Comment: @S.Guyton Do you remember how long it was? Under 5 words, 5-10 words or more than 10?

Comment: It has to be 5-10 words.

Comment: I think you guys mean 5-10 letters

Comment: @seanmus Habits. Habit. Abit. Bit. It.

Answer (score 0):

As younger people seem to like less formal words, and try to express themselves with words a 4th grader can understand, if there is such a term available, perhaps the term you're looking for is "dead set".
as in "My Grandfather and his deadset view of things " left no room for talking about why accepting people with ways different than he felt was completely the right thing to do"

? but.. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

I think the "right" word **for a more educated person** would be one of the **other choices**.

"dead set" only means he is 'set' in his ways without necessarily casting any light on the nature of how he is set.

> ***dead set***
>   [ded set for 1, 2; ded set for 3] 
>   ~ adjective
>
> 1.
>   firmly decided or determined; resolved:
>
> *His family was dead set against the marriage.*

Comment: It is a lesser used word. I have only heard it in person once or twice and read it a few more times than that.

Comment: @S.Guyton perhaps I'm dating myself or it's a term my family uses.  I agree that a word or phrase people don't use or understand is nearly useless.